# Facebook C# SDK Windows Phone logout

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8, facebook-c#-sdk

I have implemented a method by which a user can get a FB token on a windows phone 8 application. This is implemented via the Facebook C# SDK.

However, it seems that the client's token is cached, since the webbrowser control does not prompt for credentials anymore after the first logon.

Can anyone point out how to implement a logout method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Facebook credentials are stored in a cookie, so if the implementation of a logout method simply consists of clearing cookies.

If your app targets Windows Phone 8, there is a new simple API for doing that: [ClearCookiesAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj571211%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Sample code:

```
await new WebBrowser().ClearCookiesAsync();
```

Here is a tutorial that makes use of it: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Integrate_Facebook_to_Your_Windows_Phone_Application